# $01^*01^*(0 \lor 1)^* \lor 10^*10^*1(0 \lor 1)^*$ is wrong

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I have the following finite automata. I would like to know its regular expression. I gave $01^*01^*(0 \lor 1)^* \lor 10^*10^*1(0 \lor 1)^*$, but it seems my answer is wrong. Can you tell me why?

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to tell why you got the answer you did, since you have not told us your reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems (almost) correct to me. I guess what you meant was
$$01^*01^∗\color{red}{0}(0∨1)^∗∨10^∗10^∗1(0∨1)^∗$$

Comment: (+1) I just made the correction stand out a little better.